# Mac/iPhone: Is there a way to get a thread identifier without using Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, macos, pthreads

Is there a way to get any kind of thread identifier of the currently running thread without resorting to Objective-C's NSThread.

I'm improving our custom debug tracing system to handle multiple threads properly. For each  line of trace output, I'd like to print a thread id or a thread name. Threads are instantiated in various ways, e.g. both NSOperationQueue and pthread functions are used.

I've currently a following two alternatives, but I'm not satisfied with either of them. Are there any other options?

**pthread_t option**

`pthread_t` seems to be a typedef of a platform specific `_opaque_pthread_h`. It would be ok to use fields of `_opaque_pthread_h` for now, even if it's hack-y and not portable. It has a `__sig` field of type long, but that seems to have a same value for all threads of my process.

**NSThread option**

`[NSThread name]` requires `NSAutoreleasePool` to be in place, but I don't want that to be a requirement as most of our code is pure C++, so it would be nice to just to launch c++ function without autorelease pool wrapping.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a one way that is enough to get some kind of unique identifier for trace output.

`pthread_mach_thread_np` can be used to get a thread identifier, an unsigned int on iPhone.

```
mach_port_t tid = pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self());
```

Apparently this is a same thread id that is used in NSLog output.

Comment: Oh, this is SO much better than the method I was using before - setting and retrieving values in the thread's NSDictionary. Thanks! (Supporting OSX 10.4.)

Comment: Doesn't `pthread_mach_thread_np` suffer the same limitations as `pthread_self`? Namely, `thread_id` reuse more frequently then expected/desired?

Comment: @Teemu: Is it okay to call `pthread_mach_thread_np` from the application.For some reason, I don't see any man pages  for this api. But only exposed in `pthread.h`

Comment: @Vivek, I haven't lately submitted an app using it to AppStore (I'm currently using it in a Swift project), but I did in 2010. I assume it is still kosher, but note that if you are using GDC and stuff, it is mainly useful for logging. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1

Comment: NSLog out put is the same with pthread_threadid_np

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate this is a pretty old question.

To get the same `Thread ID` that is reported in macOS's `Console.app` I used:

```
uint64_t tid;
pthread_threadid_np(NULL, &tid);
printf("%#08x\nr", (unsigned int) tid);
```

A screenshot from `Console.app` on macOS.

[image]

Comment: yes, and threadid obtained is the same with result of activity monitor

Answer (score 1):

See `pthread_getname_np`.

Unfortunately NSThread's name is not currently pushed down to that.  The NSThread name is just an ivar, so there will be no way to get at it except through the method.  You could always make a C function that makes the autorelease pool and gets the name.  Your C++ code then doesn't have to be compiled as ObjC++.

`pthread_getname_np` is probably a bit more useful than NSThread's name right now anyway.  gdb and Instruments don't know about NSThread's name, only the pthread level name.

Comment: Superb. I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately, iPhone doesn't have pthread_getname_np, so this doesn't work on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

One disadvantage of using a Mach port name to identify a thread is that the name returned is local to the calling process. If several tasks retrieve a particular task's threads (using [`task_threads`](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/task_threads.html)), each task will retrieve a different port name for a particular thread.

On OS X, you can retrieve a unique 64-bit identifier using [`thread_info`](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/thread_info.html). This identifier is global (it is the same for a given thread, no matter which task is querying it) and unique (no other thread will ever have the same ID, now or in the future, until after reboot of course - as a 64-bit value, overflow is unlikely).

(See [XNU source](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/10.10/osfmk/kern/thread.c#L176), [XNU source](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/10.10/osfmk/kern/thread.c#L959).)

Retrieve this identifier for a pthread using code along these lines:

```
uint64_t GetThreadID(pthread_t thread) {
    mach_port_name_t port=pthread_mach_thread_np(thread);

    thread_identifier_info_data_t info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t info_count=THREAD_IDENTIFIER_INFO_COUNT;
    kern_return_t kr=thread_info(port,
                                 THREAD_IDENTIFIER_INFO,
                                 (thread_info_t)&info,
                                 &info_count);
    if(kr!=KERN_SUCCESS) {
        /* you can get a description of the error by calling
         * mach_error_string(kr)
         */
        return 0;
    } else {
        return info.thread_id;
    }
}
```

(See [XNU source](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/10.10/osfmk/kern/thread.c#L1316).)

Two notes:

1. There's no documentation for `THREAD_IDENTIFIER_INFO`, or at least none that I've been able to find. So I suppose, strictly speaking, that makes it undocumented. But it's in the public headers, right next to [`THREAD_BASIC_INFO`](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/thread_basic_info.html), which *is* documented - so I'm assuming this is simply an oversight. It's not like the documentation for any of this stuff is particularly great.)
2. I don't know what the situation is on iOS, but `THREAD_IDENTIFIER_INFO` and `pthread_mach_thread_np` both appear to be available in the headers, so it could be worth a try.

Comment: In case anyone else notices the discrepancy between the type of the first parameter passed to `thread_info` on the MIT doc (`thread_act_t`) and the value passed in here (`mach_port_name_t`), it seems that (in userspace) `thread_act_t`/`thread_t` is a typedef of `mach_port_name_t`.