# What is thread ID of POSIX on mac osx

Tags: c++, macos

I just read IEEE Std 1003.1™, 2004 Edition (POSIX spec.) to make sure what is actual thread ID on mac osx. In RATIONALE section of pthread_equal() of POSIX SPEC says:

> **Implementation may choose to define a thread ID as a structure.** This allows additional flexibility and robustness over using an int. for example a thread ID could include a sequence number that allows detection of "dangling IDs" copies of a thread ID that has been detected). Since the C language does not support comparison on structure typs the pthread_equal() function is provided to compare thread IDs.

In Mac OSX, pthread_t is defined as a pointer to the structure named '_opaque_pthread_t' which has 3 members. __sig which is type long,  __cleanup_stack which is a pointer to a structure, and  __opaque which is array of type char.

My first questions are:

1. pthread_t is used to identify a thread. and it is a pointer to type '_opaque_pthread_t' in osx. So, Is this correct to say that the address of type _opaque_pthread_t represents Thread ID?
2. What is its member named __sig, __cleanup_stack, and __opaque? Is it OK I think it doesn't matter what it is as application developer?

To find out an answer for my question, I googled and then I found [this question:Mac/iPhone: Is there a way to get a thread identifier without using Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540603/mac-iphone-is-there-a-way-to-get-a-thread-identifier-without-using-objective-c)　but it raises another question.

Another question is:

1. mach_port_t is not thread ID. It is an unsigned integer type which represents a port name in GNU Mach. They are different in the meaning. but when I want to get just a unique identifier of thread. Are mach_port_t and pthread_t exchangeable at all times?

Comment: Could you elaborate for which purpose you need a thread ID? Why not stay with `pthread_t`?

Comment: I would like to get a thread ID for logging. so, finally, it would be passed to printf ( or something ) as arithmetic type.

Comment: The answer by @Vishal seems the best osx has to offer. It's not ideal for human-readable logs - ideally, you'd prefer thread ids from 1 - <number of threads> for that. But the only way to get those would be to programmatically keep track of thread creation, and that's hardly worth the effort.

Comment: I agree with you. I will adhere to `pthread_t` and `pthread_threadid_np` in this case. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OS X pthread_threadid_np, defined in pthread.h, can be used. Note the _np suffix suggests that it is an extension to POSIX.

Comment: I had a try to use pthread_threadid_np and checked _np suffix means non-portable extensions to POSIX threads at [Mac OS X Man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pthread.3.html) Thanks!!